# Android App not closing after clicking back in main screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio

if i add 2 activities in the android app and make them open each other using buttons So when I open the same screen 5,6 times and then I press the back button in android my app goes back on each screen even it goes back to the second screen from 1st screen instead of closing.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: use `finish()` each time you navigate from one activity to another

Comment: @RaBaKa78 That's only if you want to close the activity. Don't call `finish()` for activities you want to keep it in the backstack.

Comment: refer this,https://medium.com/mindorks/android-launch-mode-787d28952959

Answer (score 0):

use `finishAffinity();` insted of `finish();`